# Disassemble m68k object file and reassemble for other machine

Tags: cross-compiling, disassembly, 68000

I have some m68k (I think plain 68000) object files from an obsolete workstation.
I think there were no executables and they were linked at runtime, and there are no tools or emulators.

Is it possible to disassemble (or is it recompile) the object code on another m68k machine or even x86 machine and reassemble it? And does that code run on a different m68k machine?
Or is it possible to convert that code to another language like c?

If this would work there are probably issues with labels and hardware-specific parts like display and sound but maybe it will work on small and simple code.

I mainly want to study the code.

Comment: I would not say it's impossible, but if you don't have any documentation on the object file format, it will likely require quite a bit of reverse engineering. You can of course just disassemble everything and reason about code segments that don't make sense that they are likely data.

Comment: Thanks! I now mange to disassemble one in radare2. Decompile don't work. But does this code run on any m68k? Or how to reassemble, cross-assemble or even convert? I read that convert to C is almost impossible. Half of the file is text (error messages) but it's too difficult for a newbie to fix all labels etc, especially for long code. I have documentation on the hardware and sources of some of the object files (but not in ASM).

Comment: What platform was this originally for? Amiga? Macintosh? I could try running it on my Sega Genesis emulator

Comment: The platform is called APM Machine aka Fred Machine (Edinburgh University). Hardware details are known and many sources (in Edinburg IMP). Binaries have suffix .MOB. There was an emulator but it's not public. Files are on the EMAS site https://history.dcs.ed.ac.uk/archive/os/apm_filestore/a/

Comment: Generally speaking, if the code is purely "logic" (e.g. doing arithmetic, comparing numbers, basically anything that isn't directly outputting graphics or sound) then you should be able to copy-paste and it'll work on any other m68k. But you'll need to adjust the code responsible for actually showing the results.

Comment: Usually I don't know what kind of logic a bin code contains. But at a closer look, I think most (useful) files need LIBs and depend on hardware specific i/o. Usually object files has to be linked. I found one file and I haven't found needed libs in it but I think the file is way to small to contain all the program logic just in very few bytes. I have to try again on a generic 68k emulator like Easy68k (I encountered issues), but I think it's hard to impossible to run or convert files without a full dedicated emulation and all LIBs.